# How to create a SOAP request using PHP with a XML example?

Tags: php, soap

I have the XML below:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:proc="http://servicos.saude.gov.br/sigtap/v1/procedimentoservice" xmlns:grup="http://servicos.saude.gov.br/schema/sigtap/procedimento/nivelagregacao/v1/grupo" xmlns:sub="http://servicos.saude.gov.br/schema/sigtap/procedimento/nivelagregacao/v1/subgrupo" xmlns:com="http://servicos.saude.gov.br/schema/corporativo/v1/competencia" xmlns:pag="http://servicos.saude.gov.br/wsdl/mensageria/v1/paginacao">
    <soap:Header>
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="Id-0001334008436683-000000002c4a1908-1" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
                <wsse:Username>SIGTAP.PUBLICO</wsse:Username>
                <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">sigtap#2015public</wsse:Password>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <proc:requestPesquisarProcedimentos>
            <grup:codigoGrupo>05</grup:codigoGrupo>
            <sub:codigoSubgrupo>04</sub:codigoSubgrupo>
            <com:competencia>201501</com:competencia>
            <pag:Paginacao>
                <pag:registroInicial>01</pag:registroInicial>
                <pag:quantidadeRegistros>20</pag:quantidadeRegistros>
                <pag:totalRegistros>100</pag:totalRegistros>
            </pag:Paginacao>
        </proc:requestPesquisarProcedimentos>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

How to create a PHP request?

I am trying:

```
$soapClientOptions = array(
    'Username' => 'SIGTAP.PUBLICO',
    'Password' => 'sigtap#2015public'
);

$client = new SoapClient("https://servicoshm.saude.gov.br/sigtap/ProcedimentoService/v1?wsdl", $soapClientOptions);

$params = array(
    'codigoGrupo' => '05',
    'competencia' => '201901',
    'Paginacao' => array(
        'registroInicial' => '01',
        'quantidadeRegistros' => '20',
        'totalRegistros' => '100'
    )
);

$response = $client->__soapCall("pesquisarProcedimentos", array($params));

var_dump($response);
```

I am noob on SOAP and I have no idea to how create a correct code. The code that I use is not working. I have a Forced circuit exception.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

If you don’t want to wonder how to construct the PHP request using an OOP approach + the native PHP SoapClient class with autocompletion in PhpStorm or any decent IDE, I strongly advise you to use a WSDL to PHP generator.
Try the https://github.com/WsdlToPhp/PackageGenerator.
For the WsSecurity header, you can also use the https://github.com/WsdlToPhp/WsSecurity.